# excel, find stament adress invalid qualifier

Tags: excel, find

The find statment returns a range object, but

```
netAmount = foundsomething.Address.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

code returns an "invalid qualifier" for the "Address" but "foundsomething" is a range object so it should have an Address?

```
Sub getMonthlyNet(ws As Worksheet)

Dim netAmount As Long
Dim month(1 To 12) As String
Dim foundsomething As Range
Dim searchterm As String

month(1) = "january"
month(2) = "febuaray"
month(3) = "march"
month(4) = "april"
month(5) = "may"
month(6) = "june"
month(7) = "july"
month(8) = "august"
month(9) = "september"
month(10) = "october"
month(11) = "november"
month(12) = "december"


For i = 1 To 12

searchterm = month(i)

Set foundsomething = Application.ws.Find(What:="search term", After:=Range("V1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If (Not foundsomething Is Nothing) Then
        netAmount = foundsomething.Address.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Cells(i, 1).Value = foundsomething
        Cells(i, 2).Value = netAmount
End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
netAmount = foundsomething.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

If you use `Address` that returns a `String`, not a `Range`, and you can't call `Offset` on a string.

And this:

```
Application.ws.Find(What:="search term", ...
```

should be:

```
Application.ws.Find(What:=searchterm, ...
```

otherwise you're searching for the string "search term" and not the value